# jTextArea outprint text vertically

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextarea

At the moment I am doing actions (clicking on menu items) and these actions are being stored in an arrayList. When I click a button this text is output in a long line (each item being printed one after another). I was wondering how I can change this so that when I click the button all of the test is printed vertically. Thank You! 
Here is the code I am currently using!

```
jtaWoof.append(MyFrame.shape1.getArrayList()+"\n");
```

Comment: does `getArrayList()` return an `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Yea. Here are my getter and setter for this.

Comment: public String getArrayList() {
        return arrayList.toString();
    }

    public void setArrayList(ArrayList arrayList) {
        this.arrayList.addAll(arrayList);
    }

Comment: your getter method returns a String, not ArrayList<String>. it should probably be `public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() { return arrayList; }`. You should add more code to the question to make it clearer. also show expected/actual output

Comment: that worked..thank you so much I really appreciate it! I am sorry about the poor explanation.

Comment: No problem. you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark beside it if you found it useful

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you appending the contents of the ArrayList in one go. You should use a loop to iterate through the ArrayList and append each entry to `jtaWoof`:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = MyFrame.shape1.getArrayList();
    for(String s : list){
        jtaWoof.append(s);
        jtaWoof.append("\n");
    }
```

Comment: I would make a minimal change `jtaWoof.append(s); jtaWoof.append("\n");`

Comment: @nachokk Is that for improved readability or is there a performance impact?

Comment: don't know how smart is jvm, but when you concatenate with +, a stringBuffer is created internally , and creates a new string, if you use as a literal, then it will pooled and always the same instance. I really don't know about performance impact